# DateTime.ParseExact() confusing

Tags: c#, datetime

Why I can apply that code to other form .cs

```
string dt = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

It always show error this

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

It have to change like this

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"  -->   "d/M/yyyy"
```

But in other form .cs, that code works. Don't need to change that string

Comment: Can you provide your input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying `dd` and `MM` you require the input to be 2 characters wide.Your code will work for `10/10/2015`, but not for `1/1/2015`.

Change your code to allow single day and month characters and you will be fine:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "d/M/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: what will happen if day is 2 charatcers wide in case **d** ?

Comment: It will parse it correctly. `d` allows 2 characters too.

Comment: To make this answer complete, you should change the parse string to `"d\\/M\\/yyyy"`, otherwise it won't work in locales that don't use `/` as a date separator. This is because \ doesn't match \, but instead matches the date separator for the current locale. If you escape it using \ it will verbatim match `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variables day and month does not contain leading 0 and that's why your parsing is not working. Here are some references to the MSDN page were you can find out more about [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`dd/MM/yyyy` requires two digits for the day and month, as in `10/09/YYYY`; whereas `d/M/yyyy` accepts one or digits!

Read about the [format codes on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

The code `dt = day + "/" + month + "/" + year` will not add leading zeroes to day and month.

I suggest using a [DateTime constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), as in

```
 DateTime newDate = DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Then you will not have any issues with string formats.

Answer (score 0):

if you know date parts, there is a simple way to construct `DateTime`:

from ints:

```
int day = 1;
int month = 1;
int year = 2015;
DateTime newDt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
Console.WriteLine(newDt);
```

from strings:

```
string sday = "1";
string smonth = "1";
string syear = "2015";
DateTime newDts = new DateTime(int.Parse(syear), int.Parse(smonth), int.Parse(sday));
Console.WriteLine(newDts);
```

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fFN4gm)